# Mysql server becomes unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

So I'm executing some SQL statements on a table and the MySQL server randomly stops.

Restarting MySQL fails and I'm forced to reboot the entire server each time this happens...

This is the output of `sudo journalctl -xe`

```
Apr 01 23:04:28 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 kernel: Killed process 1366 (mysqld) total-vm:1105844kB, anon-rss:160592kB, file-rss:0kB
Apr 01 23:04:28 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Apr 01 23:04:28 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 01 23:04:28 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 01 23:04:28 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 01 23:04:28 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 01 23:04:28 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Apr 01 23:04:29 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 01 23:04:58 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 01 23:04:58 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 01 23:04:58 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 01 23:04:59 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 01 23:04:59 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 01 23:04:59 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Apr 01 23:04:59 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 01 23:05:15 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 sudo[2113]: ilankleiman : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ilankleiman ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Apr 01 23:05:15 ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01 sudo[2113]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ilankleiman(uid=0)
```